# Can't install libssl-dev, dependency problem

Tags: installation, package-management, dependencies

I'm trying to install the package `libssl-dev`, but I get the following error:

`libssl-dev: Depends: libssl1.0.0 (= 1.0.1-4ubuntu3) but 1.0.1-4ubuntu5 is to be installed`

the package `libssl1.0.0` is installed fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your software sources seems to be outdated. Run `sudo apt-get update` to get make your repository information up-to-date.