# In Ubuntu 13.04, cannot install libssl-dev

Tags: 13.04, apt, dependencies, software-installation

How can I get around the dependency problem when installing `libssl-dev`?

The problem:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (= 1.0.1c-4ubuntu8) but 1.0.1c-4ubuntu8.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

System info:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.04
Release:    13.04
Codename:   raring

$ uname -a
Linux Compy 3.8.0-30-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 22 20:52:24 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

My question looks similar to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137508/cant-install-libssl-dev-dependency-problem) - but no, `apt-get update` does not do a thing for me.

Comment: @FlorianDiesch - I did look at at, and no, switching sources to `old-releases.ubuntu.com` is quite different to adding the updates path from the same server.

Answer (score 9):

Solution is to ensure that the software sources includes updates, like so:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
$ #add the following two lines to sources.list for raring-updates

 deb http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted
 deb-src http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted
+deb http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted
+deb-src http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted

$ sudo apt-get update
$ apt-cache policy libssl-dev
```

You should see output that includes `raring-updates`

```
$ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Should work this time!